# Can't link application with mudflap

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

My application uses my shared library. Application and library must be `mudflapped` to check out of bounds reads and writes both on stack and heap. Shared library was successfully build, but while linking application I had a lot of errors.

I made a simple example that reproduces this issue. Here are steps to reproduce:

- create C++ dynamic shared library project with 2 files: h and cpp files with some class, and in h or cpp file use `#include <iostream>`
- create C++ application that uses this library (uses class from inside shared library)
- build library
- build application (here you will catch an linking error)

Here are my files:

SharedLibTest.h

```
#ifndef SHAREDLIBTEST_H_
#define SHAREDLIBTEST_H_

#include <iostream>

class SharedLibTest {
public:
    void func();
};

#endif /* SHAREDLIBTEST_H_ */
```

SharedLibTest.cpp

```
#include "SharedLibTest.h"

void SharedLibTest::func()
{}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SharedLibTest.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SharedLibTest obj;
    obj.func();

    return 0;
}
```

Building the library:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fmudflap -funwind-tables -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"SharedLibTest.d" -MT"SharedLibTest.d" -o "SharedLibTest.o" "../SharedLibTest.cpp"
g++ -rdynamic -shared -o "libshared_lib.so"  ./SharedLibTest.o   -lmudflap
```

Building the application:

```
g++ -I"/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fmudflap -funwind-tables -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
g++ -L"/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug" -rdynamic -v -o "executable"  ./main.o   -lshared_lib -lmudflap
```

Linker error output is:

```
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<unsigned long>::__digits'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<long>::__min'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<short>::__min'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<char>::__max'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<short>::__max'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<long>::__max'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<int>::__max'
/home/msviridov/work/prj/workspace/shared_lib/Debug/libshared_lib.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_integer<int>::__min'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [executable] Error 1
```

Though, if I remove mudflap compiler and linker flags for library the build of application will finish successfully.
But it's not true for vice versa.

I don't understand what does lead to such result. 
My platform is Linux Mint 13 Maya 64 bit. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `#include <iostream>` from your header file. If you want to include `iostream` do that in your source (SharedLibTest.cpp) file.

Including it in header file also includes lots of garbage for you and also may cause some reference errors like this. Create SharedLibTest.o without that include and compare the sizes of object files.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting [bug 53359](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53359) but you'd need recent 4.8 code to check. Furthermore, be advised that mudflap is for [C and very simple C++ programs](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging) so you may find false possitives (ala [bug 19319](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19319)) and it [doesn't work with DSOs yet](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24420).